# Is it still worth buying Wriggle's for high Elo junglers?

Tags: league-of-legends

It seems that Saintvicious never purchases Wriggle's anymore—he always goes double Doran's => Vampiric Scepter => Frozen Mallet or Blood Thirster.

Answer (score 2):

It depends greatly on the champion. Characters with strong AoE clears like Udyr and Mundo, don't need wriggle in order to maintain their jungling speeds.

It's a heavy early investment, but a it's for  good reason. It helps you maintain jungle control, speeds up dragon/baron, gives you all the  things you need to jungle effectively.

If you comment and tell me which junglers you like, I can tell you whether it's worth continuing to buy wriggles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the junglers I was concerned with were lee sin and riven. I noticed saintvicious never gets wriggles on them anymore and he also doesn't buy wards for dragon control which I thought was weird. Isn't it a better idea to get wriggles for the armor+dragon control+free ward? I don't quite understand why he doesn't get it with lee sin/riven.

Comment: Well to be honest, both Lee/Riven comes down to preference. The reason he avoids wriggle is to bolster is offense earlier. Instead of spending money on wriggle, he guys 2-3 doran blades, giving him a substantial damage boost, which makes his ganks more damaging. Saintvicious is a very aggressive jungler that loves to gank all day, so he's willing to sacrifice some jungling speed for more damage. I would only suggest going this route if you're REALLY comfortable and confident with these characters. Otherwise, I'd stick to wriggles. It's definitely not a disadvantage, just playstyle difference.

Comment: i see thanks for the insight, makes a lot of sense to me now lol

Answer (score 0):

On a tank junglers like malphite,nunu,udyr,volibear and such but for damage dealing junglers wriggle is a must have....

Comment: yeah I agree. I think wriggles is still okay on udyr for the ward/damage output. I should try a gp10/5 item on him instead of wriggles and see how that works out.

Comment: good luck hope it works out let me know if u get the chance...

Answer (score -2):

Its called [vampiric scepter](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vampiric_Scepter), it give a huge advantage, but i think they only get it if they are in the lead, a lot of junglers like Shyvana and Lee still get it, it gives a ward, ward = vision, vision = win, and that's 75g per 3 min, so its a great item :)

Comment: This is a good argument for what wriggles is, but doesn't explain a justification for why one should take wriggle over doran blades or GP/10.

Comment: I've never seen this that way but wriggle = 75G/3mn => 4.1 gold/10 sec but it cost twice the price of a gold item ... still intressting point of view :-D